# How to specify individual database location in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

I know the `database_dir` option controls where databases are by default. But is it possible to have many databases in different folders (or even on different disks)?

Comment: Could you just use symlinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use slash `/` symbol in database name and CouchDB will create subdirectory for such database. E.g. database with name `foo/bar/baz` will have next structure on file system:

```
/var/lib/couchdb/
+ -- foo/
     + -- bar/
          + baz.couch
```

You may preallocate such structure and setup symlinks before CouchDB will use it - CouchDB handles such case with easy. The only requirement is that destination location should be readable and writable for CouchDB.

Comment: I need to organize databases outside `/var/lib/couchdb/`. I'll use simlinks. Thanks!